# Non-reduced base locus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am looking for examples of ample line bundles over (possibly smooth) projective varieties whose base locus is either non-reduced or generically non-reduced.

The only example I can come up with is a curve of general type and generic point $p$ so that $h^0(2p)=1$.

Is there any criterion for the base locus to be (generically) reduced? Or at least of low dimension? Maybe ample line bundles on Calabi-Yau and/or Fano varieties have reduced base locus?